# Securing access to SQL Server data

Tags: sql-server, database, security

I'm building a Windows application that will go against a SQL 2008 database. Some of the table data is very sensitive but some of our users will still need at least read if not read/write access to those tables. We're going to use Windows Security to control their access to the database.

I want to know if those same users can access the data in those tables through something like Excel or MS Access? It's about blocking a bad apple from trying to steal the data inside and walking off with it. If they have read access to the data, though, is there any real way to stop them?

Sorry if this is a SQL Server 101 question, but I'm not finding good answers to the question.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: the misinformation in this thread is kinda scary.  you can **absolutely** limit access to your data to only be through your application.

Comment: I think what Nathan is trying to say is that you can accomplish this goal by writing a web application that provides the sole interface to your database. If you only offer the users interaction with the database through you application, you wont have problems. I also feel like the miscommunication to which Nathan pointed is comes from the wording of the question. If security is an issue, users shouldnt be able to hit your database period. All interface with the data should come through your secured web application. (By secured, i mean watching out for things like sql-injection.)

Comment: @James the original quesiton was about Windows apps.  I'm used to a web environment where you can more readily protect your database from prying eyes via service apps.

Comment: I'm used to a web environment too, but Windows is the direction the client wanted to go, with good business reasons. Thanks for all the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this might be to author stored procedures that fulfill all of your needs and grant all the users execute only privileges.

If you grant full read access to your users, then yes its going to be difficult to prevent them from what your talking about.

Comment: I agree with James. Granting the right access on a level that is granular enough is possible but hard when login accounts access tables directly. Where James is going at is having an extra layer between the app (=the user) and the data. I would even advice you to think about building a web service as that extra layer and protect your database from access outside the control of the web service.

Comment: you shouldn't be granting users direct permission to a database anyway.  control that at the application level.

Comment: @Nathan: But when the application runs completely on the client, you've got a problem :-)

Comment: credentials can be encrypted or made inaccessible in another fashion.

Comment: @James I did suggest doing all the database access through a WCF service, but there are performance issues. Thanks for the great suggestion about using stored procedures. We're using EF but I can still use sp's with that, so perfect!

Answer (score 6):

If they have to have read access, then you should pretty much assume they can do what they want with the data.  If you render data on the screen, you have to assume someone can write down what they see with a paper and pencil.

With that said, I'd create a service account that has permissions to access SQL Server from your application.  Control the access in your app via roles.  Do not grant any users access to your database directly - they have to go through your app.

If you try to open Access or Excel and point it to your SQL Server database, they won't have permission to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, you can create a SQL account for your application.  This will disallow any outside access from anything other than your application itself.  Of course, this would mean that access to your application itself would have to be restricted.  This is also easily accomplished by limiting read access to the executable to an active directory group which contains users whom get access.  Further to that, you application may also use active directory hooks to determine whether to allow write access for those users who need it.

That all being said though.... your biggest problem will be the physical security.  If just one user in the authenticated group is untrustworthy, then a certain acceptable usage policy, HR employee screening, and user environment checks and balances must be in place.  A proper workstation deployment policy will also be good here, allowing you to restrict removable drive usage, logging all access, connectivity details etc etc.

It's more about the operational environment at this point if you can't trust the user.

Answer (score -1):

Users could access SQL tables using linked table in Access or external data query in Excel, however the permissions are controlled by the SQL server, which means the users have read-access, they will be able to access data in read-only mode.

Comment: That's what I was expecting. So if they have read permissions in SQL Server, there's really no way to keep them from getting to the data in Access or Excel, right? And thanks for the quick feedback!

Comment: I am afraid not, however if you do give them read-only rights, you should trust them to see those data correct?

Comment: this isn't right.  you can definitely control access to sql server to only through your app, disallowing any third-party apps (excel, acces, etc) to get to your data.  see my answer.

Comment: And honestly, even if you do not have Excel/Access, there are tonnes of database clients that the user could run a query and then walk away with the data by downloading the output into a text file.